# Why Edward Turner Bennett died early

Tags: biographical-details, biology

I'd like to know, why [Edward Turner Bennett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Turner_Bennett), English zoologist, died at that early age (39 years) and was it in any connection to his work (like killed by some animal or as an effect of some disease, while on one of his scientific journeys)?

Comment: Not many details ... He died in London; see [Gent.Mag. 1836, page 332](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=inu.30000080772852;view=1up;seq=348) : E.T.Burnett's obituary : "Aug.21 At Bulstrode-st. in his 40th year".

Comment: At that time death at 39 was quite common for a middle class person (lungs deceases, metal poisoning etc.) so there is no reasons to suspect any relation with his profession. Unless you know such reasons. Then state them.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko No, I don't have such information and that's why I am asking. If there is no more detail, I think that one of your comments may be turned in full-featured answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading biographies of famous people makes an impression that until the late 19th century lifespan around 40 was not unusual:

Byron (poet) 1788-1824,
Shelley (poet) 1792-1822,
Abel (mathematician) 1902-1829,
Eisenstein (mathematician) 1823-1852,
Sadi Carnot (physicist) 1796–1832,
Mozart (composer) 1756-1791,......

and you can continue this list as long as desired. I intentionally do not use
statistical life expectancy (which is distorted by the child mortality and by people of low social status whose life expectancy was even shorter). I also do not include women who frequently died in childbirth. And certainly I do not include those who died in wars or duels or were murdered. So I am talking of middle or upper class males only who died of "natural" causes.

The "natural" causes of death were pneumonia, tuberculosis, medicine (the main "cure" of everything was bloodletting, and many drugs contained lead, mercury and arsenic), sepsis (antiseptics were introduced only in the middle 19th century).